# Connection refused after connecting 75 clients to server

Tags: java, windows, multithreading, sockets, heavy-computation

I had developed a server channel socket using below code:

```
public class EchoServer {
private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;

private final static int DEFAULT_PORT = 9090;

private long numMessages = 0;

private long loopTime;

private InetAddress hostAddress = null;

private int port;

private Selector selector;

// The buffer into which we'll read data when it's available
private ByteBuffer readBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(BUFFER_SIZE);

int timestamp=0;

public EchoServer() throws IOException {
    this(DEFAULT_PORT);
}

public EchoServer(int port) throws IOException {
    this.port = port;
    hostAddress = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
    selector = initSelector();
    loop();
}

private Selector initSelector() throws IOException {
    Selector socketSelector = SelectorProvider.provider().openSelector();

    ServerSocketChannel serverChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
    serverChannel.configureBlocking(false);

    InetSocketAddress isa = new InetSocketAddress(hostAddress, port);
    serverChannel.socket().bind(isa);
    serverChannel.register(socketSelector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
    return socketSelector;
}

private void loop() {
    for (;true;) {
        try {
            selector.select();
            Iterator<SelectionKey> selectedKeys = selector.selectedKeys()
                    .iterator();
            while (selectedKeys.hasNext()) {
                SelectionKey key = selectedKeys.next();
                selectedKeys.remove();
                if (!key.isValid()) {
                    continue;
                }
                 // Check what event is available and deal with it
                if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                    accept(key);
                } else if (key.isWritable()) {
                    write(key);
                }
            }
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            timestamp+=3;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }



    }
}

private void accept(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {

    ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel = (ServerSocketChannel) key.channel();

    SocketChannel socketChannel = serverSocketChannel.accept();
    socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
    socketChannel.setOption(StandardSocketOptions.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
    socketChannel.setOption(StandardSocketOptions.TCP_NODELAY, true);
  //  socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
    socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);

    System.out.println("Client is connected");
}

private void write(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
    SocketChannel socketChannel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
    ByteBuffer dummyResponse = ByteBuffer.wrap(("ok:" + String.valueOf(timestamp)) .getBytes("UTF-8"));

    socketChannel.write(dummyResponse);
    if (dummyResponse.remaining() > 0) {
        System.err.print("Filled UP");
    }
    System.out.println("Message Sent");
 //   key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);
}
```

}

As you can see I run it on `localhost` port `9090`. In order to testing the code for heavy connections I developed a test app that each second run a new thread and connect to the server. This is the code of my test app:

```
    public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 0;
        try {
            while (i < 10000) {
                RunnableDemo temp = new RunnableDemo("Thread-"
                        + String.valueOf(i));
                temp.start();
                i++;
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class RunnableDemo implements Runnable {
    private Thread t;
    private String threadName;

    InetAddress host = null;
    int port = 9090;

    RunnableDemo(String name) {
        threadName = name;
        System.err.println("Creating " + threadName);

    }

    public void run() {
        System.err.println("Running " + threadName);
        try {
            SocketChannel socketChannel = SocketChannel.open();

            socketChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));

            while (!socketChannel.finishConnect())
                ;

            System.out.println("Thread " + threadName + " Connected");
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
            while (true) {
                if (socketChannel.read(buffer) > 0) {
                    buffer.flip();
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.limit()];
                    buffer.get(bytes);  
                    System.out.println(threadName+ ":" + new String(bytes));
                    buffer.clear();
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Thread " + threadName + " interrupted.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Thread " + threadName + " exiting.");
    }

    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Starting " + threadName);
        try {
            host = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
            if (t == null) {
                t = new Thread(this, threadName);
                t.start();
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

The test application runs but only 75 threads can connect to the server and all thread after 75th shows below exception:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at net.behboodi.client.RunnableDemo.run(Main.java:48)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Is there any limits for number of concurrent connections to the socket? Or is there any limits on using port 127.0.0.1 and local host? The other idea is that maybe a java app or JVM can not create more than 75 thread.

I searched about them all, but do not find any answer that show me what of the above reasons is my main problem and how can I fixed the code so that I can test the app with more than 10000 concurrent thread?

Comment: It's not Java, neither by number of threads nor by socket connections. You program runs well over 100 client connections on a Linux system. Are you on windows?

Comment: Yes I am on windows. but how can I extend the number of threads in windows or linux. I am tagetting 10000 client threads.

Comment: It's not the number of threads that's causing the problem since you can start the 75th client in its own thread. It looks more like a socket resource limit to me. I'm afraid I can't help you with Windows.

Comment: What OS version are you actually running it on?

Comment: Get rid of the sleep. The Selector already blocks. Sleeping in network code is just literally a waste of time. NB (1) You don't call `finishConnect()` in blocking mode, (2) you aren't connecting threads to a ServerChannel, you are connecting client sockets to a server socket, (3) your client code doesn't handle end of stream, and (4) this is not an echo server.

Comment: @Martin , I am using windows 8

Comment: @EJP, your comment was right. I removed the finishConnect and now it is working right. If you make it an answer other users can use it better. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the sleep. The Selector already blocks. Sleeping in network code is just literally a waste of time. NB (1) You don't call `finishConnect()` in blocking mode, (2) you aren't connecting threads to a ServerChannel, you are connecting client sockets to a server socket, (3) your client code doesn't handle end of stream, and (4) this is not an echo server.
                    – EJP